Github Action Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs' for workflow defaults
I am getting the error Github Action Unrecognized named-value: 'inputs' for workflow defaults for the following Github Action workflow:
name: Test CI

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      service:
        description: Service to run CI for
        required: true
        type: string

concurrency:
  group: ${{ inputs.service }}-test-ci-${{ github.head_ref || github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./services/${{ inputs.service }}

# Rest of the workflow file...

It seems to work for the concurrency and all of the following steps. However, upon adding the defaults it always returns the above error. I have tried working-directory: "./services/${{ inputs.service }}" as well with no success. I am confused why it would be working for the concurrency group and not the working-directory. What am I missing?

So according to the docs, defaults.run cannot use contexts or expressions in this keyword.
Now, if you check Context availabilities, you can see that defaults.run does not appear to have any contexts that can be used (as opposed to concurrency which you have seen yourself). However, jobs.<job_id>.defaults.run does have access to the following contexts: github, needs, strategy, matrix, env, vars, inputs.
With this being said, the only solution I can think of is to move the defaults definition inside each job (at the least the ones that require it).
name: Test CI

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      service:
        description: Service to run CI for
        required: true
        type: string

concurrency:
  group: ${{ inputs.service }}-test-ci-${{ github.head_ref || github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  job_id:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
      working-directory: ./services/${{ inputs.service }}
    steps:
      - ...

Or, if you want to have the definition in only one place, you can define a global environment variable with the working directory you wanted to define and on each of the defaults.run per job, reference the env variable.
name: Test CI

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      service:
        description: Service to run CI for
        required: true
        type: string

concurrency:
  group: ${{ inputs.service }}-test-ci-${{ github.head_ref || github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

env:
  PWD: ./services/${{ inputs.service }}

jobs:
  job_id:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
      working-directory: ${{ env.PWD }}
    steps:
      - ...

